# Making Graph Display Horizontal using jqBarGraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph

I'm using [jqBarGraph](http://code.google.com/p/jqbargraph/) and I've run into a somewhat simple but problematic issue.  I'm limited in the amount of space that I can display the graph (~550px width, unlimited height), and can have up to 50 items being displayed at once.  Because of this, the bars themselves will appear quite small (~5px thin) which isn't easy to view. So, an easy solution would be to display the bars stacked horizontally (bars stacked top to bottom, reading left to right).  This isn't an option in the current release, has anyone experienced this before and have a simple fix, or would anyone know how to create an option for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jqPlot instead?  http://www.jqplot.com